# Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock.lock

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

After I've rebooted my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS-Server today, the MySQL-Server wasnt working anymore :

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The Error-Log said :
`Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock.lock`

The permissions for /tmp, /var/run and /etc/mysql are set correcty.
If you need any additional information, please go ahead and ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show permissions for /var/run/mysqld

Comment: @AlexanderT, owned my mysql, permissions 0755

Comment: Does the `mysql.sock.lock` file exist in that path before you try to start the server? If yes, you need to check which process has the file open and then decide what to do.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, It doesnt exist

Comment: Have you tried `systemctl restart mysql.service`? Does it help?

Comment: @AlexanderT, doent work

Comment: Also may be out of disk space.